# Can't Compare Screenshot with Images

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on my Project in Windows Forms and I have a Problem. In this Project I have to Compare Screenshot with Images from File. I have good Method for Comparison in Internet found and it seems to be working. For example: I have cuted Facebook Logo from site and saved it on Desktop. When I am comparing this Logo with itself(I am making a screenshot of a logo and than compare this screenshot with Logo) this method works correctly(it says that screenshot contains Logo) but when I am making a Screenshot on it's Site and than compare it with Logo, This Method says that Screenshot donn't contains Logo.

I am using this Compare Method:

```
public static Rectangle searchBitmap(Bitmap smallBmp, Bitmap bigBmp, double tolerance)
{
    BitmapData smallData =
        smallBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, smallBmp.Width, smallBmp.Height),
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData bigData =
    bigBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bigBmp.Width, bigBmp.Height),
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    int smallStride = smallData.Stride;
    int bigStride = bigData.Stride;

    int bigWidth = bigBmp.Width;
    int bigHeight = bigBmp.Height - smallBmp.Height + 1;
    int smallWidth = smallBmp.Width * 3;
    int smallHeight = smallBmp.Height;

    Rectangle location = Rectangle.Empty;
    int margin = Convert.ToInt32(255.0 * tolerance);

    unsafe
    {
        byte* pSmall = (byte*)(void*)smallData.Scan0;
        byte* pBig = (byte*)(void*)bigData.Scan0;

        int smallOffset = smallStride - smallBmp.Width * 3;
        int bigOffset = bigStride - bigBmp.Width * 3;
        bool matchFound = true;

        for (int y = 0; y < bigHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bigWidth; x++)
            {
                byte* pBigBackup = pBig;
                byte* pSmallBackup = pSmall;

                //Look for the small picture.
                for (int i = 0; i < smallHeight; i++)
                {
                    int j = 0;
                    matchFound = true;
                    for (j = 0; j < smallWidth; j++)
                    {
                        //With tolerance: pSmall value should be between margins.
                        int inf = pBig[0] - margin;
                        int sup = pBig[0] + margin;
                        if (sup < pSmall[0] || inf > pSmall[0])
                        {
                            matchFound = false;
                            break;
                        }

                        pBig++;
                        pSmall++;
                    }

                    if (!matchFound) break;

                    //We restore the pointers.
                    pSmall = pSmallBackup;
                    pBig = pBigBackup;

                    //Next rows of the small and big pictures.
                    pSmall += smallStride * (1 + i);
                    pBig += bigStride * (1 + i);
                }

                //If match found, we return.
                if (matchFound)
                {
                    location.X = x;
                    location.Y = y;
                    location.Width = smallBmp.Width;
                    location.Height = smallBmp.Height;
                    break;
                }
                //If no match found, we restore the pointers and continue.
                else
                {
                    pBig = pBigBackup;
                    pSmall = pSmallBackup;
                    pBig += 3;
                }
            }

            if (matchFound) break;

            pBig += bigOffset;
        }
    }

    bigBmp.UnlockBits(bigData);
    smallBmp.UnlockBits(smallData);

    return location;
}
```

This method returns a Rectangle "location". If `(location.Width == 0 || location.height == 0)`, it means that Screenshot doesn't contain Image.
What's the problem?

Comment: one possible reason is that, the screen shot uses the screen resolution, and so the screen shot size may be different from your template. In your code, you assumed that the 'logo' are the same size.

Comment: Screenshot size is allways bigger than template but when I am making Screenshot of Image(not from Browser) than it recognizes image in Screenshot . On the other side when I am making a Screenshot in Browser, it cann't recognise him.

Comment: check the logo size of 1) the screen shot from browser; 2) not from browser; very possible, the size is not the same (although maybe similar). so, in order to match them, you need consider: 1) scale of the logo; 2) instead of match RGB with small threshold, use other features, such as edge, ...

Answer (score 0):

If the screenshot contains any blank space around the border, it will most likely not match with the image (unless the screenshot is the whole screen).

Comment: I know approximately where this Logo will appear so I am making a Screenshot not on all screen, I am cuting a Rectangle from from Desktop and that Rectangle is a Screenshot and it contains not just an Image but it also contains it' Background or another Logo too.